# Prevent an order from being created if credit card is declined?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

When a user places an order on my woocommerce site, an order will be created in the back end with a pending status even if the user's credit card is declined.

I want to be able to prevent the order from being created until a successful response is recieved. I am using Authorize.net as my payment gateway.

Comment: This is a normal process… Because during transaction process, a reference within that order is sent to the credit card payment gateway,  I don't think you can avoid it. You can't guess, before this submission, if that customer credit card is going to fail…

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe I can delete the order if I recieve a failure from authorize.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use the woocommerce_order_status_failed hook to handle this use case.